# Boost::Python class with function templates: How to add instances from the outside?

Tags: python, c++, templates, boost, export

## Summary

Is there a way (in C++, not in Python) to add additional instantiations of function templates for a class in Boost::Python from the outside (by injection, reopening the definition, registering the needed instantiations, etc)?

## Background

Given a class (not a class template) containing members that are function templates, I want to generate Python bindings using Boost::Python.

However, as I am writing a library, I do not know beforehand which template parameters the member functions will be called with. That means, I cannot list them in the Boost::Python class definition.

## Example

Let's say we have a class `TheClass` that has function templates (with overloads), and two test classes `SomeClass` and `OtherClass` like this:

#### Class Definitions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    std::string Name()
    {
        return "SomeClass";
    }
};

class OtherClass
{
public:
    std::string Name()
    {
        return "OtherClass";
    }
};

class TheClass
{
public:

    template <class T>
    void Foo   (T& arg)
    {
        std::cout << "Called Foo(" << arg.Name() << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    void Bar   (T& arg, std::string param)
    {
        std::cout << "Called Bar(" << arg.Name() << ", " << param << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    void Bar   (T& arg, int param)
    {
        std::cout << "Called Bar(" << arg.Name() << ", " << param << ")" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

Then I use this code for exporting all of the above to Python:

#### Boost Python Export

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#define GENERATE_THE_CLASS_METHODS(classname)                                 \
    .def(                                                                     \
        "Foo",                                                                \
        ( void ( TheClass::* )( classname& ))( &TheClass::Foo ),              \
        ( boost::python::arg("arg") )                                         \
    )                                                                         \
    .def(                                                                     \
        "Bar",                                                                \
        ( void ( TheClass::* )( classname&, std::string ))( &TheClass::Bar ), \
        ( boost::python::arg("arg"), boost::python::arg("param") )            \
    )                                                                         \
    .def(                                                                     \
        "Bar",                                                                \
        ( void ( TheClass::* )( classname&, int ))( &TheClass::Bar ),         \
        ( boost::python::arg("arg"), boost::python::arg("param") )            \
    )

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    boost::python::class_< TheClass > ( "TheClass" )
        GENERATE_THE_CLASS_METHODS(SomeClass)
        GENERATE_THE_CLASS_METHODS(OtherClass)

        // This is the interesting part: all instantiations of the function
        // templates have to be inserted here. How can this be avoided
        // so that new classes can also be used?

    ;

    boost::python::class_< SomeClass > ( "SomeClass" );
    boost::python::class_< OtherClass > ( "OtherClass" );
}
```

(Side question: I use a macro here in order to avoid duplicated code for maintenance reasons. Is there a more beautiful, C++-ish way of achieving this?)

#### Python Test Script

The code above compiles using Clang with C++11, Boost 1.57.0 and Python 2.7.6. It works with this test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from my_module import *

s = SomeClass()
o = OtherClass()
t = TheClass()

t.Foo(s)
t.Foo(o)

t.Bar(s, 42)
t.Bar(o, 42)
t.Bar(s, "Hello World")
t.Bar(o, "Hello World")
```

Yielding this outout:

```
Called Foo(SomeClass)
Called Foo(OtherClass)
Called Bar(SomeClass, 42)
Called Bar(OtherClass, 42)
Called Bar(SomeClass, Hello World)
Called Bar(OtherClass, Hello World)
```

## Question

In the example, the instantiations of the function templates for Foo() and Bar() are created inside the Boost::Python class definition (see the comment in the source code). This means, a user of the library cannot add a new instantiation without modifying this bit of code.

Thus, what I am looking for is a way to either

- "inject" those instantiations from the outside of the Boost::Python class definition
- re-open the definition somehow
- register the needed instantiations somewhere before the Boost::Python class definition is called

In the end, a user of the library should be able to do something like this:

```
class AnotherClass
{
public:
    std::string Name()
    {
        return "AnotherClass";
    }
};

add_to_the_class(AnotherClass);
// or
add_to_class_definition<AnotherClass>("TheClass");
// or whatever works...
```

Is this somehow possible? Are there other ways to achieve something similar?

Comment: For your side question, [`boost::python::def_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/def_visitor.html) provides a generic way to non-intrusively extend classes while avoiding duplicated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while, I found a solution and figured this might be interesting for others as well.

## Solution

It is actually pretty easy: The `boost::python::class_` definition returns (of course) a class instance of type `boost::python::class_< TheClass >`. This can be stored, so we can add member definitions to it later:

```
static auto the_class_ = boost::python::class_< TheClass > ( "TheClass" )
    // add some .def(...) and so on here, if needed
;

template <class T>
void add_to_the_class()
{
    the_class_
        .def(
            "Foo",
            ( void ( TheClass::* )( T& ))( &TheClass::Foo ),
            ( boost::python::arg("arg") )
        )
        .def(
            "Bar",
            ( void ( TheClass::* )( T&, std::string ))( &TheClass::Bar ),
            ( boost::python::arg("arg"), boost::python::arg("param") )
        )
        .def(
            "Bar",
            ( void ( TheClass::* )( T&, int ))( &TheClass::Bar ),
            ( boost::python::arg("arg"), boost::python::arg("param") )
        )
    ;
}
```

Now we can add as many extra overloads to this definition from the outside as we want:

```
add_to_the_class<AnotherClass>();
```

This also gets rid of the ugly macro.

## Some additional insight

This all works because the actual binding to Python is created at runtime. In your boost::python binding code, you actually just define some classes and functions -- which are called before main() to initiate the actual connection between your C++ code and the Python interpreter.

I think, this is not well documented in the boost::python help. It took me a while to figure this out. In the beginning, I thought that boost::python somehow (via some template magic) produces the bindings during compile time. If this was true, the solution above would not work. In hindsight, this is all clear to me now.

Furthermore, this insight (binding is done at runtime, using the definitions you provide) also gave me the idea to write a static register class that collects classes to be exported to Python. This would help my library approach even further, as I would not have to extend the main `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` definition for each new class, but instead simply register the class to the static register (probably using some macro again...). But this is future work... Problem solved for now!